# differences between "Cognos TM1 and "Cognos 10 BI

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

What the differences between "Cognos TM1" and "Cognos 10 BI"?
Which one is consider as BI Tools by IBM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are huge differences between "Cognos TM1" & "Cognos 10 BI"!

**Cognos TM1** is a (OLAP) multidimensional database which can be queried from Excel and the Web through "TM1 Web", "TM1 Executive Viewer" and "Cognos 10 BI". Within this database, you'll be able to create almost anykind of OLAP / Decisional application.

**Cognos 10 BI** is a web based reporting application. Users, depending on their rights (licence) will be able to run reports, schedule reports and/or create ad hoc analysis against relational and/or multidimensional databases. In order to do so, a logical layer has to be built using "Framework Manager". This logical layer is used to hide database complexity and to provide to the end users relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

In simplest terms:

- TM1 is a database engine and a collection of applications for accessing and managing its databases.
- Cognos BI is a collection of web applications that provide pretty interfaces for viewing and doing stuff with data.

More often than not, Cognos BI uses TM1 databases as its data source, but it does not have to. If Cognos BI is using TM1, most of the same user functions that are possible in TM1 applications are also available through Cognos BI, except they are available in a more user-friendly manner. Cognos BI also adds functionality not in TM1 applications to allow additional data management. IBM's marketing is confusing, but generally Cognos BI and Cognos TM1 collectively are considered to be *the* BI Tools package that they offer.

Now to be a little more technical about TM1, it is not just a plain old database. As others here have mentioned, it is a multidimensional OLAP database. It is able to handle numeric and string data, but it does not have a concept of NULL values. Numeric data can be summarized using consolidated elements. It has attributes to store metadata in. It has a built-in rules engine to handle business logic and custom calculations. It has processes for ETL and database maintenance tasks. It has chores for scheduling processes at various intervals. It links to Excel workbooks. Lastly, in addition to these features and more that are provided out of the box, TM1 exposes an API for programming against using 3GLs such as C++, C#, Java, and even VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference is Cognos TM1 is meant to work with excel easily wheras Cognos 10 BI is mainly browser based.
Have a look here for gory details.
http://www.tm1forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1442

Answer (score 0):

Cognos TM1 is also referred to by IBM as Financial Performance Management FPM. It's an in-memory MOLAP cube application with real-time rules calculation. As it provides end-user writeback it's often used by the Office of Finance for budgeting and modelling - therefore the MS Excel interface is frequently used. However it also comes with a zero footprint web "front end" as well as Cognos Insight, which permits distributed or disconnected access to the TM1 cubes (located server side).

TM1 may be integrated into Cognos BI, so that Cognos BI reports from TM1 cubes; or TM1 may be accessed from a portlet within a Cognos BI dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

difference between cognos10 and cognos tm1 :-BI is the reporting tool and cognos tm1 is analysis and reporting tool , in tm1 bulid the CUBES and BI generatead the reports